# What is $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta^{\chi_l(\sigma)}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, group-actions, characters

> What does the following mean ?
>
> $$\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta^{\chi_l(\sigma)}$$

$\sigma\in {\rm Gal}(\bar{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)$ and $\chi_l:{\rm Gal}(\bar{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)\to\mathbb Z_l^{\times}$ and $\zeta$ is any $l^n$-th root of unity, how do you exponentiate that thing ?

I know Galois group, l-adic cyclotomic character and group actions in general.

Answer (score 2):

If $\zeta$ is a $l^n$-th root of unity, then $a^{\chi_l(\sigma)}=a^{\chi_l(\sigma) \pmod{l^n}}$, where we used the projection map $\Bbb Z_l^\times \to (\Bbb Z/l^n\Bbb Z)^\times$.

Comment: Why is this nowhere mentioned, in none of the sources. Thanks a lot.